useSortBy() return posssible unhanlde promise rejection
Could you please help me with Algolia useSortBy?
I created a replice index for this called items_search_replica and I added price_asc and price_desc sorting attributes to it.
These are the sorting options:
  const sortByItems = [
    { value: "items_search", label: "Relevant" },
    { value: "items_search_replica_price_asc", label: "Price (asc)" },
    { value: "items_search_replica_price_desc", label: "Price (dsec)" },
  ];

This is my component for sorting:
import { useSortBy } from "react-instantsearch-core";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import RadioButtonGroup, { RadioButtonItem } from "expo-radio-button";

const CustomSortBy = (props) => {
  const {
    currentRefinement,
    options,
    refine: refineSortBy,
  } = useSortBy({ items: props.items });

  return (
    <View className="border-b border-b-slate-200">
      <Text className="labelText font-extrabold text-md dark:text-white my-3">
        Sorting
      </Text>

      <View className="p-1 rounded-md">
        <RadioButtonGroup
          containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
          selected={currentRefinement}
          onSelected={(value) => refineSortBy(value)}
        >
          {options.map((item, index) => (
            <RadioButtonItem
              key={index}
              value={item.value}
              label={<Text style={{ color: "black" }}>{item.label}</Text>}
            />
          ))}
        </RadioButtonGroup>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CustomSortBy;

I get "Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0)" and I don't understand why!
The useSortBy() is not async function
Here is the link to the docs that I followed: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/sort-by/react/#hook

There are some slightly different rules to follow for react-native. I dont know if they are the caused of errors but they could be https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/

Yes, i have followed these steps, the only thing not working right now is the Sorting unfortunally
